# secure iPhone WebApp with jqTouch and HTML5

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jqtouch, web-applications

I have a little WebApp (just one html-File with 200 lines of code) running on a free webhosting provider. I want to have limited access to the WebApp, so not everyone can see the page. I also need only one user with password to login.

Is it possible to easy integrate a user login only in Javascript, JqTouch and html?

Answer (score 2):

You could encrypt the meaningful source, and on initial launch just have a text field that requires the user the enter the key:

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/demo/

here's a sample page to get you started: http://robotwoods.com/dev/so_crypt.html

Here's the code (I know links are suspicious):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<head>
<title>Encrypted Site</title>
<style>
body {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#wrap {position:relative; width:500px; height:550px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
#pwd {position:absolute; width:120px; top:100px; padding-left:170px; height:50px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>
<script>
//--------------HERE IS THE ENCRYPTED CONTENT
kt="{iv:\"oMnhqxC9DhBgaZjHvm354g\",salt:\"gxZ08m1I5DY\",ct:\"TIKmKXfzkWaxBJ0nbyMVYo9/tvmlIeuIE4Aknt7j7H4t+bk\"}";
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="wrap"><div id="main">
    <div id="pwd">S.O. Username:<input id='pass' type='text'/><button onclick="login_test()">Login</button></div>
</div></div></body>

<script>
function login_test(){
    try{document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=sjcl.decrypt(document.getElementById('pass').value,kt);}
    catch(err){document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<div id=\"error\" style=\"color:#F00\"><br/>This is not for you</div>';} 
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With only Javascript you can but you shouldn't do it : Everyone can see it.
Please, consider using a server-side language (such as PHP, ASP or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one page, then no. Even if you hid stuff behind a login (which is doable), anyone could figure out what was happening by just looking at the html code, as javascript, jqtouch and html are all client-side.

You would need to implement something else on the server-side to authenticate and then deliver content.

If you only care about showing a login and don't really need security, then you can implement a login and such for demonstration purposes.